# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'answer')

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a command whereas it fetches another bot's embed title and checks if it exists in my JSON file. In my code, I'm trying to get my bot answer a riddle by another bot.
This is what I'm trying to do:
[image: embed]

This is my code (in the @456 bot):

```js
const riddle = [
    {
      "riddle": "What has to be broken before you can use it?",
      "answer": "egg"
    },
    {
      "riddle": "I’m tall when I’m young, and I’m short when I’m old. What am I?",
      "answer": "candle"
    },
    {
      "riddle": "What month of the year has 28 days?",
      "answer": "all of them"
    },
    {
      "riddle": "What is full of holes but still holds water?",
      "answer": "sponge"
    },
    {
      "riddle": "What question can you never answer yes to?",
      "answer": "Are you asleep yet?"
    }
]
const id = args[0]
    if (isNaN(id)) return;
const msg = await message.channel.messages.fetch(id);
    if (!msg) return;
const answer = riddle.filter((obj) => obj.riddle === msg.embeds[0].title).answer
const emb = new MessageEmbed()
     .setAuthor(msg.embeds[0].title)
     .setDescription(msg.embeds[0].description)
     .setColor(msg.embeds[0].color)
message.channel.send({content: `__**Answer:**__ ${answer}`, embeds: [emb]})
```

I get an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'answer')` whenever I try to run this code. I also tried separating the riddle to a JSON file before. It worked but it gave me an `undefined` answer. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the case so you can study the filter, and understand the return behavior, as well as the output you want, which I show in the console.log:

```json
const riddle = [
    {
      "riddle": "What has to be broken before you can use it?",
      "answer": "egg"
    },
    {
      "riddle": "I’m tall when I’m young, and I’m short when I’m old. What am I?",
      "answer": "candle"
    },
    {
      "riddle": "What month of the year has 28 days?",
      "answer": "all of them"
    },
    {
      "riddle": "What is full of holes but still holds water?",
      "answer": "sponge"
    },
    {
      "riddle": "What question can you never answer yes to?",
      "answer": "Are you asleep yet?"
    }
];
const msg = {
    embeds:
        [
            {
                title: 'What question can you never answer yes to?',
            }
        ]
};

const answer = riddle.filter((obj) => obj.riddle === msg.embeds[0].title);
console.log(answer[0].answer);
```

you can make this more robust, but this will show you how the structures and filters work, which is your problem at hand.

Comment: Although your simplified code works but I don't think that's what I'm trying to get. The embed where I'm trying to get the riddle from is not anywhere in my code. That is why I have the `const msg = await message.channel.messages.fetch(id);`. It's another bot's embed which I don't I have access to. I'm trying to get another bot's embed title. I tried to make my code like yours above but I changed the `msg` to `await message.channel.messages.fetch(id);` whereas the `id` = `args[0]`.
Now I got an error, `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'answer')`. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: you need to fetch a message, to get the details.  if you know the ID of the other bot's message, then you use that as "id" in your fetch call.  You can also do other things like get the ID of the message author and compare it to the other bot's ID, to make sure you're getting a message from the other bot and not someone else.

Comment: the reason I stripped out all the message fetching and stuff is because your issue was in your filter and getting the answer, which is what I'm showing you in the sample code, how it works.  if you run what I have, you'll see it prints the answer desired, and not "undefined"

Comment: I did fetch the message with `await message.channel.messages.fetch(id);` the `id` is the message id of the other bot... I don't know what else I did wrong or was there something that I missed to add?

Comment: it's the message ID or the bot ID?  if you console.log(msg), what do you get?